# How to add a radio button to a form with Zend Framework?

Tags: forms, zend-framework, zend-form

the issue is not so much as adding a radio button form element but how to i match it in my script format. It looks like there are multiple ways of doing things in zend.

here is my script:

```
 $this->addElement('text', 'time_from', array(
        'id' => 'datepicker',
        'class' => 'time_from',
        'filters' => array('StringTrim', 'StripTags'),
        'required' => true,
        'label' => 'Start Date of the Week: ',
        'value' => ''
    ));

    $update = $this->addElement('submit', 'update', array(
        'required' => false,
        'ignore' => true,
        'label' => 'Change Time'
            ));
```

based on this template, how do i add a radio button?

i believe a logical approach would be to use something like this:

```
$this->addElement('radio', 'test', array(
            'label'=>'Test Thing',
            'addMultiOptions'=>array(
                'male' => 'Male',
            'female' => 'Female'
            ),
    ));
```

but this doesn't display any radio buttons.

I've also tried to replace  the :

```
'male' => 'Male',
'female' => 'Female'
```

with and array, but i get all kind of errors:

```
array('male'=>'Male', 'female'=>'Female')
```

any ideas on how to do this?

and , if is ot too much to ask maybe someone can explain why so many ways to do this forms and what is the common nominator in between them.

thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You were quite right, but since you construct the element with `addElement()` you don't have `addMultiOptions` (the function name), it's just `multiOptions`.

```
$this->addElement('radio', 'test', array(
    'label'=>'Test Thing',
    'multiOptions'=>array(
        'male' => 'Male',
        'female' => 'Female',
    ),
));
```

You can see a summary of all [Zend_Form elements here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.standardElements.html) Edit: updated link.

Comment: Set a default option by adding `'value' => 'male'` in the same format as `'label' => 'Test Thing'`